# gettting an error while defining the event name on mysqlworkbench 5.5

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, mysql-5.5, mysql-event

I created a stored procedure like the following:

```
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`MailMe`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_archivev3`()
BEGIN

INSERT INTO 
     send.sgev3_archive(a_bi,
                        b_vc,
                        c_int,
                        d_int,
                        e_vc,
                        f_vc,
                        g_vc,
                        h_vc,
                        i_dt,
                        j_vc,
                        k_vc,
                        l_vc,
                        m_dt,
                        n_vch,
                        o_bit)
SELECT     a_bi,
           b_vc,
           c_int,
           d_int,
           e_vc,
           f_vc,
           g_vc,
           h_vc,
           i_dt,
           j_vc,
           k_vc,
           l_vc,
           m_dt,
           n_vch,
           o_bit

FROM   send.sgev3

WHERE m_dt BETWEEN  CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND CURDATE();


END
```

Now, I am trying to create an event inside the above stored procedure as follows:

---

```
-- Routine DDL
-- Note: comments before and after the routine body will not be stored by the server
-- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`MailMe`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_archivev3`()

EVENT archivescheduler

ON SCHEDULE

EVERY 10 SECOND

DO BEGIN

INSERT INTO 
     send.sgev3_archive(a_bi,
                        b_vc,
                        c_int,
                        d_int,
                        e_vc,
                        f_vc,
                        g_vc,
                        h_vc,
                        i_dt,
                        j_vc,
                        k_vc,
                        l_vc,
                        m_dt,
                        n_vch,
                        o_bit)
SELECT     a_bi,
           b_vc,
           c_int,
           d_int,
           e_vc,
           f_vc,
           g_vc,
           h_vc,
           i_dt,
           j_vc,
           k_vc,
           l_vc,
           m_dt,
           n_vch,
           o_bit

FROM   send.sgev3

WHERE m_dt BETWEEN  CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND CURDATE();


END
```

I am getting a `cross` symbol on the line `EVENT archivescheduler` in the above code. I am following the following [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-event.html) on the MySQL Website. Am I doing something wrong?

What I suspect is that since I have already created the stored procedure before and I am trying to create one, this could create some problem. Please let me know what I am doing wrong?

As small screenshot from the MySQLWORKbench of the error: [image: error]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per documentation you can't create event inside procedure body. See this post [Create an event inside a procedure - SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8357174/create-an-event-inside-a-procedure-sql).

You will have to create the procedure first and then call it from event like below

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`MailMe`@`%` PROCEDURE `sp_archivev3`()
BEGIN

INSERT INTO 
     send.sgev3_archive(a_bi,
                        b_vc,
                        c_int,
                        d_int,
                        e_vc,

<Rest of the code goes here>
```

Then create event calling the procedure

```
DELIMITER $$  
CREATE EVENT archivescheduler
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 10 SECOND
DO BEGIN
    CALL `sp_archivev3`();
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Another Pointer: In case your stored procedure don't fire from event; you may need to check whether `GLOBAL EVENT SCHEDULER` is in `DISABLE` state. You can turn it on using below setting

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Comment: Thanks. So basically I need to create another stored procedure where I can create event code that you mentioned above and run that stored procedure one time. This will run the stored procedure `sp_archive()` every 10 sec ?

Comment: @rocky, NO; have your SP and then create the event separately ... call your SP within event as have shown in answer. Bottomline, you can't create event within procedure body.

Comment: So basically you are saying that the answer you have written baove needs to be run in MySQL work bench just like a SQL statement? So far I have seen only Stored Procedure related code where we start from `DELIMETER $$ CREATE EVENT ... & so on ..`. I don't see any option of creating an `EVENT` just like we have an option for creating a `Routine`. Please clarify. Thanks

Comment: @rocky, Yes; `create event` yes again a separate routine (kind of) cause it's alltogether a separate DB object. Look into MySQL doc for more info.

Comment: Could you tell me where exactly you are referring to in your documentation  http://www.peregrinesalon.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/mysql-stored-procedures.pdf  ? The documentation is 98 pages documentation. Because, creating a routine and then defining event is again "Defining an Event inside a Procedure" , which is not possible. Thanks

Comment: @rocky, that's how it should be. It's more a bug to MySQL (check in google or MySQL Spec). See this doc http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-program-restrictions.html. It says `An event may not be created, altered, or dropped by a stored routine, trigger, or another event. An event also may not create, alter, or drop stored routines or triggers. (Bug #16409, Bug #18896)`