# How to create event in MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-event

I have problem with creating trigger in MySQL workbench. 
I read this post [working with triggers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542475/working-with-events-in-mysql) and found there isn't any event part in UI interface of workbench but we can write event SQL query in work branch.

I wrote it and run it but it doesn't run. also when I run show events; there is not any events in the list.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
delimiter |
CREATE EVENT `TestEvent` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 day

DO BEGIN
insert into test2 (id, source, name)
select id, source, name from test1
END 

delimiter ;
```

How can I solve it?

Comment: You have to use the delimiters: `from test1; END |`

Comment: Thank you for your help. It works:)