# Event scheduler in Waiting for next activation state for long time

Tags: mysql, scheduler, mysql-event

I created an event and now when use `SHOW PROCESSLIST` command on my MyQLWorkbench window, I see the following message for my event.Please see the following Image[image]:

The above fields in the image corresponds to Id,Host,db,Command,time,State,Info respectively.

It's in `"Waiting for next activation"` state for ever. I don't know why and I believe that's the reason my event isn't running.

Read the documentation [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/event-scheduler-thread-states.html) but it doesn't seems to explain much about troubleshooting or any solution.

I already ran the following command:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Here is the result of the Query `SHOW EVENTS FROM MyDB`

[image]

Result of `SELECT * FROM mysql.event` (Since the result was so long, I am adding the image in two parts as below)

**Part 1** [image]

**Part2:**[image]

Comment: What's the result of `SELECT @@event_scheduler;`? If it is `DISABLED` you can't start the event scheduler at runtime.

Comment: @VMai Result is `ON` for the command `SELECT @@event_scheduler;`

Comment: Have you got any events created?

Comment: How should I check for that? I did follow the create event syntax mentioned over here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24542475/working-with-events-in-mysql

Comment: I think event has been created because when I tried to create the event with the same name, I wasn't able to and got the message that event already exist

Comment: You can get that with `SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS WHERE EVENT_NAME='your_event_name_goes_here' AND EVENT_SCHEMA='your_database_name'`. Add the result to your question please.

Comment: I used `SELECT * FROM MyDB.events
WHERE EVENT_NAME = myeventname`


But I got the message " Error Code: 1146 Table 'MyDB.events' doesn't exist.

Comment: Okay, so the command is `SHOW EVENTS  FROM MyDB`.

Comment: The result is similar to the more complicated statement of me. But you've got to post the result. Edit it into your question please.

Comment: Added the result, please check @VMai

Comment: Well it's a recurrent one, and it isn't executed, while it should be executed every 10 seconds. You could look at the error log, but you could tell me the output of `SELECT EVENT_DEFINITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.EVENTS WHERE EVENT_NAME='myeventname' AND EVENT_SCHEMA='MyDB'`. That's the SQL statement that should be executed every 10 seconds.

Comment: @VMai I ran the query you mentioned and got a result under `EVENT_DEFINITION` as follows: `BEGIN CALL MyDB.mystoredproc()  END` . Please let me know if it looks good.

Comment: That leads us to the definition of your stored procedure. You'll get that with `SELECT ROUTINE_DEFINITION FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_NAME = 'mystoredproc';`

Comment: @VMai That gives me everything from `BEGIN INSERT INTO .... END` just like mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24212273/gettting-an-error-while-defining-the-event-name-on-mysqlworkbench-5-5 between `BEGIN` and `END`. May I know why are we following these steps?

Comment: We want to find out, why your event doesn't get executed, don't we?

Comment: Yes. What should be our next step then?

Comment: What's the result of `SELECT * FROM mysql.event`? Please regard it's not `mysql.events` as you wrote earlier.

Comment: @Vmai Please find the results updated in my question above (Two images: Part 1 & Part 2)

Comment: OK, looks good. And it said last_executed not so long ago.

Comment: Although it said, last executed not so log ago, it doesn't look like my event is running because I manually ran the SP long time back and got some results inserted into some table from another table and I still see same number of records inserted into it.

Comment: My mistake. I had the name of the stored procedure misspelled while  running the event and that's why the event wasn't doing anything :)

Thanks for your help @VMai